# NullpointerException during getWindow().getAttributes();

Tags: java, android, screen-brightness

I am trying to fetch the screen brightness in Android.

The scenario is such that Class A calls a function of Class B as:

**Class A:**

```
if(condition is true){
  ClassB.function();
}
```

**Class B:**

```
function(){
WindowManager.LayoutParams screenBrightness = getWindow()
                    .getAttributes();
screenBrightness.screenBrightness = 1;
screenBrightness.flags |= WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON;
screenBrightness.flags |= WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD;
screenBrightness.flags |= WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED;
getWindow().setAttributes(screenBrightness);
}
```

The exception received is as:

```
06-15 13:36:30.476: E/AndroidRuntime(8873): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-15 13:36:30.476: E/AndroidRuntime(8873): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-15 13:36:30.476: E/AndroidRuntime(8873):     at function(B.java:68)
06-15 13:36:30.476: E/AndroidRuntime(8873):     at something.run(A.java:104)
06-15 13:36:30.476: E/AndroidRuntime(8873):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
06-15 13:36:30.476: E/AndroidRuntime(8873):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-15 13:36:30.476: E/AndroidRuntime(8873):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
06-15 13:36:30.476: E/AndroidRuntime(8873):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3701)
06-15 13:36:30.476: E/AndroidRuntime(8873):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-15 13:36:30.476: E/AndroidRuntime(8873):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-15 13:36:30.476: E/AndroidRuntime(8873):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
06-15 13:36:30.476: E/AndroidRuntime(8873):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:624)
06-15 13:36:30.476: E/AndroidRuntime(8873):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Has anyone faced this issue earlier?

Comment: what is line 68 @ `B`?

Comment: @shayanpourvatan Its "WindowManager.LayoutParams screenBrightness = getWindow().getAttributes();". After debugging further I got to know that getWindow() is returning null hence the error. But I am confused as Class B activity is visible on screen.

Comment: both class A and class B is an activity class? you need create static method and pass context of activity to that function,

Comment: @shayanpourvatan  Yes, both A and B are activity class. You mean Class B should be created as static class. Any other alternatives than this? I tried using this.getWindow() but still the same issue,

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem when I called `transaction.commit()`.

After changing it to `transaction.commitAllowingStateLoss()` the problem went away.

Comment: Use upper case letters if they are needed. Format the inline code correct.

Answer (score 0):

try following code:

```
if(condition is true){
  ClassB.function(this);
}
```

and function is:

```
public static void function(Activity activity){

    WindowManager.LayoutParams screenBrightness = activity.getWindow()
                    .getAttributes();
    screenBrightness.screenBrightness = 1;
    screenBrightness.flags |= WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON;
    screenBrightness.flags |= WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD;
    screenBrightness.flags |= WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED;
    activity.getWindow().setAttributes(screenBrightness);
}
```

if you want use this approach better to see [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18865060/passing-reference-to-activity-to-utility-class-android) because pass reference of activity is not a good approach.

but as i see your problem is better to use SharedPreference to save brightness in Class A and use that in class B,

you can see [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624280/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-in-android-to-store-fetch-and-edit-values) for understanding how to use `SharedPreference` in android, for fetch set and edit value.

if you have any question about that you can ask me.

Comment: If we call "ClassB.function(this);" from Class A it will pass the context of Class A, right? How will it access the getWindow() of class B instead? Just curious, haven't tried it yet.

Comment: i dont get you? you want to know how you must call that from class B?

Comment: Just noticed that getWindow() will be accessible under Activity.class and its not defined under Context.class. Can you please check it?

Comment: Its like I want to set the brightness of Class B. If I call that function from Class A it will change brightness of A and it won't reflect over B. Do you have any other suggestion to do it?

Comment: you can use SP for saving value in Class A and set brightness in onResume() of class B, then all time that you comes to this class your brightness being refreshed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55642/discussion-between-raj-and-shayan-pourvatan).